# Using directed graph How to put agency list in a table though pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, graph

hello I'm a beginner & I'm currently using directed graphs for a project. I want to put the values of an agency list into a table but I'm not using pointers right, I need help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void addNewEdge(vector<int> adjacencyList[], int a, int b)
{
  adjacencyList[a].push_back(b);
  adjacencyList[b].push_back(a);
}

void viewGraph(vector<int> adjacencyList[], int nodes, int *tab[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++)
  {
  

    for (int j=0; j<adjacencyList[i].size() ; j++)
        {
            *tab[i][j]= adjacencyList[i][j];
        }

    cout<<endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int nodes = 5;
  int tab[100][10];
  vector<int> adjacencyList[nodes];

  addNewEdge(adjacencyList, 0, 1);


  viewGraph(adjacencyList, nodes, *tab[][]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void addNewEdge(vector<int> adjacencyList[], int a, int b)
```

This is wrong.

You need to pass your adjacency vector by reference, not by value.  That way when you add the nodes, they are added to the vector you passed, not a local copy.

Like this:

```
void addNewEdge(vector<int>& adjacencyList, int a, int b)
```